# Как поставить стороннее ПО на MSPOS-K с МТС или LiteBox

Tags: android, файлы

Есть кассовый аппарат MSPOS купленный с ПО LiteBox. На аппарате ОС Android, но нет Play Market, что бы загрузить приложения из него. Вместо этого стоит какой-то урезанный магазин приложений, в котором всего пара приложений. Можно ли как-то накатить на него apk с нужным приложение? Обращался к сервисным инженерам, никто ничего не знает. Говорят такая же проблема на кассах MSPOS-K от МТС.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если возможно зайдите в настройки, в о телефоне или устройстве, нажимайте Номер сборки, вы получить возможности разработчика, выйдите обратно в настройки нажмите для разработчиков, там включите  ВКЛ, и отладка по USB, подключите USB к ПК, и через adb вы сможете устанавливать приложения. Скорее всего разработчики не просто так сделали, что сделали, лучше для Вас не лезьте.

Comment: Скачал adb driver с https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools выполнил из консоли команду: adb devices, пишет unauthorized

Comment: Обычно диалог появляется с подтверждением доступа для отладки, если нет возможно производитель запретил внешним разработчикам подключатся.

Answer (score 2):

Если unauthorized, то надо сбросить заводские настройки.

1. Делаем HARD RESET.
2. Заходим НАСТРОЙКИ - ВОССТАНОВЛЕНИЕ И СБРОС. Далее следуем инструкции.
3. MSPOS-K попробует перезагрузить ОС, может зависнуть, тогда принудительно жмем питание, выключаем и включаем заново.
4. Ждем белого экрана с надписью HELLO.
5. Качаем ADB драйвер под вашу ОС отсюда

   https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools
6. Распаковываем драйвера в папку `c:\TEMP\platform-tools\`, сюда же кладем apk с нужным ПО.
7. На ПК из командной строки выполняем `adb devices`
8. Затем `adb install path/to/file.apk`
9. После установки, завершаем настройку `MSPOS-K` и после загрузки видим установленное приложение.

Comment: Есть, заработало! Вся фишка была в сбросе заводских настроек. Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0):

**Бесполезное занятие.** В ближайшее время устройство будет запускать только LiteBox/ МТС кассу и вы ничего не сможете с этим поделать. Лучше обратиться в техподдержку МТС Кассы и сообщить, что в продукте вас не устраивает.